# How to choose an angle of incidence?

Tags: aerodynamics

How to choose an angle of incidence?

Looking at typical airfoil polars, it seems most classic NACA GA wing airfoils like the NACA2415, have similar properties:

1. A max Cl/Cd at about 5-7deg
2. Lowest drag on the drag polar between -5 and +5 deg, then drag increases substantially outside of this range.
3. 0 Cm at about 10-15 deg.

Interestingly, these ranges don't really overlap.

Also, I understand for maximum efficiency, we should design a plane
to cruise at 0 moment.

So ...do we choose the angle of incidence with the lowest drag, or the highest Cl/Cd, , or 0 Cm and then adjust airplane geometry for a CMplane of 0 at cruise?

Based on the above data, my intuition says to:

determine the cl needed for Vcruise, determine the AOA needed to generate that lift on the lift curve, and check that that angle of incidence is about 2deg, near the highest Cl/Cd vs Alpha at 5-7 deg, which still gives me a bit of leeway before the drag really increases past +5 deg, , and then adjust airplane geometry to get a CMplane of 0 at my chosen Vc.

Is this correct?